# How to find specified combinations of array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have an array of objects:

```
var arr = [{a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}, {a:3}, {a:2}, {a:6}, {a:7}, {a:8}, {a:4}];
```

Sum of a values is equal 36. I need to divde this array on 3 small arrays with 3 elements on each one. And the main condition, that all sets should have the same sum of a values (if it is impossible, than sets with the smallest deviation from each other). So the average value of each set should be `36/3 = 12`
In output I want to receive:

```
var comb = [[{a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}], [{a:3}, {a:2}, {a:6}], [{a:7}, {a:8}, {a:4}]];
```

But of course with correct elements.
And other main thing, that array can be from different count of elements (max size 40) and array can be devided on any number of sets. For example:

```
var arr = [{a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}, {a:3}, {a:2}, {a:6}, {a:7}, {a:8}, {a:4}, {a:4}];
```

devide on 5, and I should receive:

```
var comb = [[{a:1}, {a:2}], [{a:3}, {a:3}], [{a:2}, {a:6}], [{a:7}, {a:8}], [{a:4}, {a:4}]];
```

I would appreciate for any help.

Comment: Just to clarify, do all the ending sets have to be the same size, even when a different split would be more even? For example, if you have to split ``{1,1,1,3}`` into 2 sets, is the answer ``{1,1}, {1,3}`` or ``{1,1,1}, {3}``?

Comment: They have to be tha same size, in your case it is {1,1}, {1,3}.

Comment: If the splits have to be equal in element counts, forget my answer with the pile of stones...

Comment: You need to try all combinations, end examine the deviations.

Otherwise how would you know the deviation is the smallest one ?

It is a similar problem like this one http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1005

http://people.csail.mit.edu/bdean/6.046/dp/ - here you can train your DP skills useful for solving such NP problems

Comment: I have already tried to use all combinations, but this way is to slow, and if array has a many elements, than browser can crash, because in this case I make many unnecessary iterations